# Error: call: argument fn is undefined or null (Redux Saga)

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, redux-saga, saga

I am calling an API through the redux-saga. For that, I am using "call". But I am getting an error:
Error: call: argument fn is undefined or null

In this js file, I have written redux-saga code. Which takes form credentials and then passes it to the register.js

auth.saga.js:

```
    function* asyncRegistration(action) {
  const {
    orgName,
    orgUrl,
    timeZone,
    adminName,
    adminEmail,
    adminphone,
    password,
  } = action.payload;

  const result = yield call(
    register(
      orgName,
      orgUrl,
      timeZone,
      adminName,
      adminEmail,
      adminphone,
      password
    )
  );

  console.log("saga", result);
}

export function* watchEveryAuth() {
  yield takeEvery(REGISTRATION_CREDENTIALS, asyncRegistration);
}
```

In this js file, I am calling the API for results.

register.js:

```
    import axios from "axios";

export const register = (
  orgName,
  orgUrl,
  timeZone,
  adminName,
  adminEmail,
  adminphone,
  password
) => {
  try {
    const res = axios.post(
      "http://amnius-connect.ebizontech.biz/amnius-connect/api/admin-registration",
      {
        organization_name: orgName,
        organization_website: orgUrl,
        time_zone: timeZone,
        username: adminName,
        email: adminEmail,
        phone: adminphone,
        password: password,
      }
    );
    console.log("our result is ", res);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Please suggest a solution:

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the function as first parameter of the `call` effect, as you have it right now you have an expressions that first calls the reigster function and then the result of that is used as first parameter which is not what you want.

```
const result = yield call(
  register,
  orgName,
  orgUrl,
  timeZone,
  adminName,
  adminEmail,
  adminphone,
  password
);
```